# How do I overcome my permission denied error when running with sudo?

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo, rpm

I’m using the following version of Linux …

```
[davea@mydevbox ~]$ uname -a
Linux mydevbox.evo-text.com 4.4.5-15.26.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 16 17:15:34 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I’m tryihng to install node.js but I’m getting the below permission denied error, even though I’m running with sudo.  What else do I need to do to run this command successfully?  Below is what happens

```
[davea@mydevbox ~]$ sudo curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | bash -

## Installing the NodeSource Node.js 4.x LTS Argon repo...


## Inspecting system...

+ rpm -q --whatprovides redhat-release || rpm -q --whatprovides centos-release || rpm -q --whatprovides cloudlinux-release || rpm -q --whatprovides sl-release
+ uname -m

## Confirming "el7-x86_64" is supported...

+ curl -sLf -o /dev/null 'https://rpm.nodesource.com/pub_4.x/el/7/x86_64/nodesource-release-el7-1.noarch.rpm'

## Downloading release setup RPM...

+ mktemp
+ curl -sL -o '/tmp/tmp.PfqaTA4YLm' 'https://rpm.nodesource.com/pub_4.x/el/7/x86_64/nodesource-release-el7-1.noarch.rpm'

## Installing release setup RPM...

+ rpm -i --nosignature --force '/tmp/tmp.PfqaTA4YLm'
error: cannot open Packages index using db4 - Permission denied (13)
error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm
Error executing command, exiting
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo bash -

basically, it's the bash command that needs to be run as sudo, not the curl